# With Google Maps API, How to fill a a html table with all visible markers on current zoom level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have an empty html table and a google map with some markers on it. All the markers are stored in an array.
When the user zooms in the map, markers location should fill the empty table.
So, how would I achieve this?

[image]

```
        <div id="MapRender"></div>


            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Location</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxx"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadGoogleMAP() {

        var mapProp = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('MapRender'), mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.592360,76.733660),
            map: map,
            optimized: false,
            title: 'Place1'
        })

        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.174507, 88.777137),
            map: map,
            optimized: false,
            title: 'Place2'
        })
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', LoadGoogleMAP);

</script>
```

Comment: can you share a demo on jsfiddle or codepen as the info provided can lead to different approaches to solution.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Yeah sure...

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I have added the code. Please see.

Comment: have you tried 'zoom_changed' event provided. I think use that event to access your zoom and do your specified work. I think you have tried this, then on zoom which marker position you want to show, as there are many markers. Do we need to create an array for markers. If yes, which one to choose to show after map zoom ?

Comment: See : `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    // your logic 
});`

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: myLatLng is not defined`.  What array are all the markers stored in?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.